# Istio rate limiting for external services

Tags: kubernetes, istio, envoyproxy

I struggle with adding rate limiter to istio mesh for outbound traffic from my cluster to the external service. All the examples in the docs are related to istio ingress gateway.

1. What would be the pattern here? Should I use egress gateway and configure envoy filter there or configure Service Entry first that matches my external service e.g. google.com  and attach envoy filter to it?
2. How to add the envoy filter to egress/Service Entry?

Answer (score 0):

Use egress gateway and configure envoy filter there like in this [example](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/450b8f06912743ded8169445c9a8ec42a08de499/tests/integration/telemetry/policy/testdata/enable_envoy_ratelimit.yaml).

You can find more information about this configuration [here](https://discuss.istio.io/t/envoyproxy-rate-limit-not-working-in-istio-1-7/8122).